# SimpleINI library - can't compile a code with SI_NO_CONVERSION defined

Tags: c++, ini

I use [SimpleINI](https://github.com/brofield/simpleini) library on Linux. There is the following comment:

```
// Defines the conversion classes for different libraries. Before including
// SimpleIni.h, set the converter that you wish you use by defining one of the
// following symbols.
//
//  SI_NO_CONVERSION        Do not make the "W" wide character version of the 
//                          library available. Only CSimpleIniA etc is defined.
//  SI_CONVERT_GENERIC      Use the Unicode reference conversion library in
//                          the accompanying files ConvertUTF.h/c
//  SI_CONVERT_ICU          Use the IBM ICU conversion library. Requires
//                          ICU headers on include path and icuuc.lib
//  SI_CONVERT_WIN32        Use the Win32 API functions for conversion.
```

When I try to compile the following code:

```
#define SI_NO_CONVERSION
#include "SimpleIni.h"

int main()
{
    CSimpleIni ini;
    return 0;
}
```

I get the compilation error: `‘CSimpleIniA’ was not declared in this scope` It looks like SI_NO_CONVERSION is not defined in SimpleIni.h. Could you explain what's going on ?

Comment: On Windows building also fails.

Comment: The web page says it's a c++ project, not a c project. You need to change your tags, removing c and adding c++.

Comment: The project's README.md is out of date with respect to the code but if you edit the readme's examples a bit, then you'll get it to work. It's not a well-maintained project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SimpleIni.h` only defines `SI_Case` and `SI_NoCase` when either of `SI_CONVERT_GENERIC`, `SI_CONVERT_ICU` or `SI_CONVERT_WIN32` is defined. This leaves `SI_Case` and `SI_NoCase` undefined when (only) `SI_NO_CONVERSION` is defined, which causes the `CSimpleIniTempl` template instantiation to fail, with the related compile errors. This is an oversight/bug in the library and should be reported to the author.

As a workaround, adding the missing definitions before `#include "SimpleIni.h"` gets the code to compile.

```
#define SI_NO_CONVERSION

#define SI_Case     SI_GenericCase    // ***
#define SI_NoCase   SI_GenericNoCase  // ***

#include "SimpleIni.h"

// ... etc ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The doc you included says it all:

> Only CSimpleIniA etc is defined [when SI_NO_CONVERSION is defined].

Below is an edited version of the first example in the `README.md`. The SI_ASSERT macro is defined in the header file but the ASSERT_EQ and ASSERT_STREQ macros, referenced in the example, are not. It's almost unforgivable that someone's examples don't compile.

***As I mentioned in a comment, this is not a well-maintained project. The instructions for building and testing don't work in a very obvious way. Seems like the developer has files in his working copy that aren't in the git repository. Inexcusable.***

Additionally, I get extra compilation errors when I define SI_NO_CONVERSION. Don't use this project. Use something else instead.

```
#include "SimpleIni.h"

int main () {
    CSimpleIniA ini;
    ini.SetUnicode();

    SI_Error rc = ini.LoadFile("example.ini");
    if (rc < 0) { /* handle error */ };

    const char* pv;
    pv = ini.GetValue("section", "key", "default");

    ini.SetValue("section", "key", "newvalue");

    pv = ini.GetValue("section", "key", "default");
}
```

You compile this with something like `g++`.

Comment: It doesn't answer my question. What about with using SI_NO_CONVERSION ? Please explain it.

Comment: Why not use [this](https://github.com/benhoyt/inih) instead? At least the example in the README.md works without much editing.